# Add New Constraints boxes showing standard and can't enter values in them

Tags: xcode, xcode11, xcode11.2.1

It's weird, all of sudden Add To Constraints shows Standard and entering any value inside them isn't accepted. I can change these values from Size inspector. This weird problem happens when I try to pin the subviews to superview. If I position subview well off sides then this issue doesn't happen.

Any clue why it's happening?
[image]